# How to look up and combine data in different parts of an XML source document using XSLT to create SVG visualization of a finite element mesh

Tags: javascript, css, xml, xslt, svg

### Background

In my job as an engineer, I often use [a finite element analysis program](http://www.candeforculverts.com/home.html) for analyzing buried structures in soil. The underlying code is excellent, but the UI - especially the ability of the program to create and display the input finite element meshes - is limited, and leaves much to be desired. I am attempting to create a better, faster viewing experience for the XML formatted mesh data using javascript, CSS and SVG graphics in the browser.

I think I understand XML and SVG. However, my XSLT programming experience is *-zilch-*; the W3Schools tutorial has helped a little bit, but I am having trouble finding good resources online to go deeper in learning what I need to know. Would greatly appreciate it if someone could at least help me get started in solving this problem. I am eager to learn not just how to do it, but how to write my own XSLT transformations in the future.

### Specific Problem

My idea at this point is to represent each element in the finite element mesh as an SVG polygon. However I am having trouble understanding how to "look up" the X and Y values for each node of every individual polygon and have the coordinates inserted into the right places.

Here is the structure of the type of XML input file I have to work with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CANDEMeshGeom>
   <Control>
      <numNodes></numNodes>    <!--   # of nodes   -->
      <numElements></numElements>    <!--   # of elements   -->
      <numSoilMaterials></numSoilMaterials>    <!--   # of soil materials   -->
      <numInterfaceMaterials></numInterfaceMaterials>    <!--   # of interface materials - not relevant   -->
      <inputCheck></inputCheck>    <!--   not relevant   -->
      <numBoundCond></numBoundCond>    <!--   # of boundary conditions - not relevant   -->
      <numConstIncr></numConstIncr>    <!--   # of construction increments   -->
      <LevelNum></LevelNum>    <!--   not relevant   -->
      <Heading></Heading>    <!--   Mesh heading   -->
      <meshTitle></meshTitle>    <!--   Title of the mesh   -->
   </Control>
   <nodeData>    <!--   all of the nodes are listed first   -->
      <nodeCoord>    <!--   a node   -->
         <nodeNumber></nodeNumber>    <!--   the integer node #   -->
         <nodeXCoord></nodeXCoord> <!--   the X coordinate, floating point #   -->
         <nodeYCoord></nodeYCoord> <!--   the Y coordinate  floating point # -->
      </nodeCoord>

      <!--   more nodes....   -->

   </nodeData>
   <elementData>    <!--   all of the elements listed 2nd   -->
   <!--   All elements are defined by 4 nodes: I, J, K, L. Note that there are 3 kinds of elements: Beam, Triangle, and Quad. A beam element repeats the 2nd (J) node number three times. A triangle element repeats the 3rd (K) node number twice. The quad element has 4 different node numbers.   -->
      <elemConn>
         <elemNumber></elemNumber>    <!--   each element has a unique #   -->
         <elemNode1></elemNode1>    <!--   element I node # (from nodes defined above)   -->
         <elemNode2></elemNode2>    <!--   element J node   -->
         <elemNode3></elemNode3>    <!--   element K node   -->
         <elemNode4></elemNode4>    <!--   element L node   -->
         <elemMatNum></elemMatNum>    <!--   element's material type #   -->
         <elemConstrIncr></elemConstrIncr>    <!--   element's construction increment #  -->
         <elemType></elemType>    <!--   type of element: BEAM, TRIA, QUAD   -->
      </elemConn>

      <!--   more elements....   -->

   </elementData>
   <boundaryData>
   <!--   the boundary data isn't relevant to producing the graphical mesh output above   -->
   </boundaryData>
   <soilData>
   <!--   the soil data also isn't relevant   -->
   </soilData>
   <interfaceData>
   <!--   the interface data also isn't relevant   -->
   </interfaceData>
</CANDEMeshGeom>
```

The SVG file output would be structured like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!--   a <polygon> element for every <elemConn> in the input file    -->
    <!--   the 'points' attribute is populated by "looking up" the <nodeXCoord> 
        and <nodeYCoord> based on the nod number inside of <elemNode1>, <elemNode2>,
        <elemNode3>, and <elemNode4>     -->
    <polygon points="<!--elemNode1X-->,
                     <!--elemNode1Y--> 
                     <!--SPACE-->
                     <!--elemNode2X-->,
                     <!--elemNode2Y-->
                     <!--SPACE-->
                     <!--elemNode3X-->,
                     <!--elemNode3Y-->
                     <!--SPACE-->
                     <!--elemNode4X-->,
                     <!--elemNode4Y-->
                     "/>
</svg>
```

Here is an example of the kind of result I am looking to produce (the different colors represent different materials). The XML file associated with the image below can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/361ijz4oqc3rijk/Full%20Mesh%207ga%20%2818ft%29_MeshGeom.xml)

[image: Expected Result]

### Future Plans

I also want to be able to toggle the colors of elements between representing the material of the element or the construction increment. Later on I will try to add even more functionality, like displaying the node and element numbers, displaying boundary conditions (with labels), things like that. Perhaps I will even extend the capability so you can *edit* the mesh in the browser as well (right now I am stuck with editing text-based input files by hand... *sigh*).

*NOTE: This question (including the title) has been heavily edited; the original version was too broad, since I didn't really know what I was asking. Many thanks to [@helderdarochaless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3190413/helderdarocha) and [@Kevin Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491227/kevin-brown) for helping me figure that out.*

Comment: I suggest you add a *simple* XML source and the expected SVG *XML code* you would expect to obtain (as well as any XSLT you've tried so far). It's best to concentrate on a specific aspect of your transformation you are having trouble with, and then create one or more follow-up questions if you feel the need.

Comment: That's good advice. I just didn't really know where to start - I could write the expected output SVG file though, that's a good idea. Should I start a new question...?

Comment: You might edit this one, since it has no answers and already a close vote. SVG is XML. If you write an objective question focusing on the XML transformation (showing the code that is read and generated, rather than the image), you have better chances.

Comment: @helderdarocha: is this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a mini XML and sample XSL that is just a taste to jump start your creation. This should get you started in your project (which looks like a great one). Given this cut down sample XML:

```
<CANDEMeshGeom>
    <nodeData>
        <nodeCoord>
            <nodeNumber>1</nodeNumber>
            <nodeXCoord>5</nodeXCoord>
            <nodeYCoord>5</nodeYCoord>
        </nodeCoord>
        <nodeCoord>
            <nodeNumber>2</nodeNumber>
            <nodeXCoord>10</nodeXCoord>
            <nodeYCoord>5</nodeYCoord>
        </nodeCoord>
        <nodeCoord>
            <nodeNumber>3</nodeNumber>
            <nodeXCoord>10</nodeXCoord>
            <nodeYCoord>10</nodeYCoord>
        </nodeCoord>
        <nodeCoord>
            <nodeNumber>4</nodeNumber>
            <nodeXCoord>5</nodeXCoord>
            <nodeYCoord>10</nodeYCoord>
        </nodeCoord>
    </nodeData>
    <elementData>
        <elemConn>
            <elemNode1>1</elemNode1>
            <elemNode2>2</elemNode2>
            <elemNode3>3</elemNode3>
            <elemNode4>4</elemNode4>
        </elemConn>
    </elementData>
</CANDEMeshGeom>
```

You could use this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <svg>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//elemConn"/>
        </svg>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="elemConn">
        <polygon>
            <xsl:call-template name="drawpoly"/>
        </polygon>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="drawpoly">
        <xsl:attribute name="points">
            <xsl:call-template name="getpoint">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodenum" select="elemNode1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="getpoint">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodenum" select="elemNode2"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="getpoint">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodenum" select="elemNode3"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="getpoint">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodenum" select="elemNode4"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="getpoint">
        <xsl:param name="nodenum"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="//nodeCoord[nodeNumber=$nodenum]/nodeXCoord"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//nodeCoord[nodeNumber=$nodenum]/nodeYCoord"/>        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which would yield this sample output XML:

```
<svg><polygon points="5,5 10,5 10,10 5,10"/></svg>
```

You can certainly expand on this to make it real SVG, add your color ideas and more. This is simply demonstrating the "lookup" you need to find the needed X,Y information from the element node numbers.

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for without knowing it, and it is perfect. I will edit the question to fit this answer and then mark this as the accepted answer, and then later split the other aspects of things I need help with into future questions.